# How can I simplify using variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python. How can I simplify this into a single line using variables?

```
print (my_list [0] + " " + my_list [1] + " - " + my_list [2] + " - " + my_list [3] + " , " + my_list [4] + " , " + my_list [5])
print (my_list [6] + " " + my_list [7] + " - " + my_list [8] + " - " + my_list [9] + " , " + my_list [10] + " , " + my_list [11])
print (my_list [12] + " " + my_list [13] + " - " + my_list [14] + " - " + my_list [15] + " , " + my_list [16] + " , " + my_list [17])
print (my_list [18] + " " + my_list [19] + " - " + my_list [20] + " - " + my_list [21] + " , " + my_list [22] + " , " + my_list [23])
print (my_list [24] + " " + my_list [25] + " - " + my_list [26] + " - " + my_list [27] + " , " + my_list [28] + " , " + my_list [29])
print (my_list [30] + " " + my_list [31] + " - " + my_list [32] + " - " + my_list [33] + " , " + my_list [34] + " , " + my_list [35])
print (my_list [36] + " " + my_list [37] + " - " + my_list [38] + " - " + my_list [39] + " , " + my_list [40] + " , " + my_list [41])
print (my_list [42] + " " + my_list [43] + " - " + my_list [44] + " - " + my_list [45] + " , " + my_list [46] + " , " + my_list [47])
print (my_list [48] + " " + my_list [49] + " - " + my_list [50] + " - " + my_list [51] + " , " + my_list [52] + " , " + my_list [53])
print (my_list [54] + " " + my_list [55] + " - " + my_list [56] + " - " + my_list [57] + " , " + my_list [58] + " , " + my_list [59])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `python3.6` ,
you can use fstring which also helps you to format your string

```
my_list=[i for i in range(60)]
def printarray(listarray):
        print(f"{listarray[0]} {listarray[1]} - {listarray[2]} - {listarray[3]} , {listarray[4]} , {listarray[5]}")
for i in range(0,60,6):
        printarray(my_list[i:i+6])
```

OUTPUT

```
0 1 - 2 - 3 , 4 , 5
6 7 - 8 - 9 , 10 , 11
.....
48 49 - 50 - 51 , 52 , 53
54 55 - 56 - 57 , 58 , 59
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this into  one line using a for loop:

```
for i in range(0, 60, 6):  print(my_list [i] + " " + my_list [i+1] + " - " + my_list [i+2] + " - " + my_list [i+3] + " , " + my_list [i+4] + " , " + my_list [i+5])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I substitute the last three numbers with the average of those numbers?

Comment: @antoniomunro Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

```
total_elements = 60
elements_in_one_line = 6
for i in range(total_elements ):
    if i%elements_in_one_line  == 0:
        print()
    print(my_list[i],end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

split into sub-arrays of 6 elements and append each elements in the sub-array.

The one line code is

```
composite_list = [ my_list[x] + " " + my_list[x+1] + " - " + my_list[x+2] + " - " + my_list[x+3] + " , " + my_list[x+4] + " , " + my_list[x+5]  for x in range(0, len(my_list),6)]
```

Please have a try with the following sample code.

```
import random

my_list = map(str, random.sample(xrange(100), 60))
print(my_list)
composite_list = [ my_list[x] + " " + my_list[x+1] + " - " + my_list[x+2] + " - " + my_list[x+3] + " , " + my_list[x+4] + " , " + my_list[x+5]  for x in range(0, len(my_list),6)]
print(composite_list)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be slow? and even more complicated than the original code?

Comment: Not sure about the performance. @antonio munro asked 'single line with variables', that is why I assigned the result into a variable . I think both our answers are same, but you were very quick...

Comment: I assume the list contains string objects because the original code does not use str(my_list[0]). Also your answer has more than 1 line

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I edited the answer and removed  string casting.

Comment: Much better now

Comment: It was a full sample, including sample data and imports. Core logic has only one line. I have edited my answer